# Find the magnitude of each vector and the angle it makes with respect to the $+x$ axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

A) Ax = 3, Ay = -2
I got 3.6m for the magnitude and -33.6 degrees for its angle. However the answer is 300 degrees.

B) Ax = -2, Ay = 2
I got 2.8 M for the magnitude and -45 degrees for its angle.
I seem to be calculating the angles wrong but I dont know what I am doing wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your work looks correct.

For A),
$$A_x =3, A_y = -2 \implies |A| = \sqrt{3^2 + 2^2} \approx 3.6.$$
The angle it makes with the $+x$-axis is
$$\arctan \left( \frac{-2}{3} \right) = -33.7^\circ.$$

B) looks fine too.